# написать MERGE такой как в SQL

Tags: c#

как написать MERGE с помошью LINQ в c#?

```
MERGE TargetProducts AS Target
    USING SourceProducts    AS Source 
    ON Source.ProductID = Target.ProductID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (ProductID,ProductName, Price) 
        VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, Source.Price)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Target.ProductName = 'new';
```

Comment: Какую ORM используете?

Comment: @aepot dapper..

Comment: Напишите об этом в вопросе, так же укажите, что именно не получается. Вы же пытались что-то сделать, верно? Покажите код.